# Reinstalling Test app on Titanium

Tags: android, titanium

I'm trying to test my application on my phone. I have successfully done it before but for some reason it seems to not be updating with the latest version. I uninstall my app from my phone, I build my application in Titanium for Android. I go to install now and it appears to install it on the device. I open the application and it is in the same state I left it in and has not appeared to have been updated. Driving me nuts!!!!!!

Comment: What Ti Dev tool are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest version. 1.2.2

Comment: my bad I meant are you using TiStudio or TiDeveloper but I assume 1.2.2 is a TiDeveloper version number

Comment: Have you tried updating (just add a line) the tiapp.xml file? This should force a rebuild across the board.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your app's identity has changed, so when adb goes to install the app, the phone rejects your new version. This could happen if you installed a signed version of the app, and then went back in to development of it.

Try uninstalling the app from your phone, and then deploying it again. With a fresh slate, you should be able to get it working again!

Hope this helps; let me know if it doesn't and we can explore some other solutions! -Dawson